# get current date in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: date, blackberry, java-me, date-format

how to get current date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format in BlackBerry

i have already tried the following, but it gives me output of `1318502493`

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

System.out.println("Current time in :" + currentTime);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
private String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
String dateInString =new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date());
```

Comment: Personally I would use the parameterless constructor of `Date`, as that will already get the current time. This way *is* more explicit though.

Comment: and how to get responce in this format  "Friday Octomber 14" ?if you have any idea plz help me

Comment: I just want to get the time How can i get it?

Answer (score 8):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
return formatter.format(new Date());
```

Comment: That "DD" will be the day of the *year* which is almost certainly *not* what the OP really wants.

Comment: Good point, just used the pattern he gave, but you have a point :)      
(edited)

Comment: I just want to get the time, how can i get it?

Answer (score 3):

Check if you can use SimpleDateFormat. If you can, create an object of this class, and use it in order to format the return provided by System.currentTimeMillis(). Some code below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DateTest {
  public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
       SimpleDateFormat formDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

       // String strDate = formDate.format(System.currentTimeMillis()); // option 1
       String strDate = formDate.format(new Date()); // option 2
       return strDate;
  } 
  public static void main (String args[]) {
       System.out.println(getCurrentTimeStamp());
  }
}
```